# Laravel 4: Session is not working in server

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

session::set and session::get is not working in laravel

Session is working in local machine. But when I test in live server, it is not working.

Scenario: While logging into an application `Auth::attempt` returns `true`. But again it redirected to login page. This is an exact issue.

`Auth::check` method return `true` under the `auth::attempt` condition.
But in login page and filter.php, `Auth::check` method return `false`.

I don't know why :(

I tested it with a laravel session variable. I assigned a value in a session variable and redirected the page to another page where I have echoed the session. It return empty.

Additional Detail: It does not retain the session flash message in server. It is working in local.

Please advice.

Comment: can you include the code where you set and get the session data, and maybe also the redirect?

Comment: @nozzleman: Thanks! I used Session::put('test', 'test string'); for testing purpose. My problem is auth:check return false. But auth::attempt return true. I don't know why. That's why I thought, it might be belongs to session issue. I'm not sure. Please advice.

Comment: @nozzleman: Additional info, It does not retain the session flash messages in server. It is working in local

Answer (score 1):

If your session driver is `file`, then make sure your (storage) path is writable by PHP. Look for this in your session.php file:

```
'driver' => 'file',
....
'files' => storage_path().'/sessions',
```

Comment: By default I have cookie as driver. Session works If I change it into file. But auth:login does not work.

Comment: Always Auth::check return false :(

Comment: If you're using cookies, check your `domain` configuration in `session.php`. Set it to: `'domain' => null`.